# How to integrate SFDX with REST

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

My goal is to download all attachments of a given Case.
I was managed to perform the needed queries to and I have a pointer to the ContentVersion object I need.

They problem is that I don't know how to download the attachment. I believe I need the VersionData field, which holds the file in binary format.

Another limitation that I have is that I'm using a Linux environment by means of its CLI prompt.
I already made an authentication to SF by using SFDX API provided by SalesForce, but I cannot find a way to combine SFDX API with REST API's GET command to fetch the needed file so it will be downloaded to my Linux machine.

Please advise.

Uri

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) to retrieve [attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm#:%7E:text=Retrieves%20the%20specified%20blob%20field%20from%20an%20individual%20record.&text=Because%20blob%20fields%20contain%20binary,XML%20to%20retrieve%20this%20data.&text=For%20an%20example%20of%20retrieving,Attachment%20Content%20from%20a%20Record.).

As you already have the ContentVersion Id you can fetch VersionData and FileExtension by an SOQL and then can simply run a curl command

```
curl <your_instance_url>/ContentVersionData -H "Authorization : Bearer {access_token}" -o nameOfFile
```

Comment: instead of getting the needed file, I'm getting a small text file with the following data in it

Comment: var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
if(window.location.search && window.location.search.length > 1){
    url += window.location.search; // #189617
}



var loc = 'https://*********.salesforce.com?ec=302&startURL='+encodeURIComponent(url);
window.location = loc;
</script>

Comment: when I put manually the URL in my web browser, the needed file being successfully downloaded.

Comment: Not sure where this get wrong but I was able to download file successfully. Might be an issue with filename. it should be name.fileExtension

Comment: I'm trying to download a.tar file, and I'm naming it myfile.tar.